# What options do I have, to replace Apache web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server

I need a web server that runs php and does not create so many processes (today I checked the running processes list and there were like 90 of them called 'httpd', 300kb each), I only know these but I don't know if they will do the same or not:

- ngix
- lighttpd

Comment: The number of processes that apache makes is a function of the configuration you are using. The number it will make is also related to the load on the server.  Other web servers have strengths as well as weaknesses when you need to run php, but the primary thing to realize is that there will be substantial configuration required to get these to work with php.  And they will still create socket connections.

Comment: You can limit the number of times apache forks. MaxClients http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients can limit the total max, MaxSpareThreads will limit the extra copies that will run over current connections, and MinSpareThreads will say how many to keep running over the current connections.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What options do I have, to replace Apache web server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/313684/what-options-do-i-have-to-replace-apache-web-server)

Answer (score 5):

Check the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software) article for a detailed comparison of webservers. In the list, the worth noticing web servers are,

1. nginx
2. lighttpd
3. LiteSpeed Web Server and
4. Cherokee HTTP Server

However, each of these are different in terms of configuration and it really depends on your requirement to choose an appropriate alternate.

OR

You can simply tune your apache for performance and continue using it.