# What options do I have, to replace Apache web server?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, web-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What options do I have, to replace Apache web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/313673/what-options-do-i-have-to-replace-apache-web-server)

I need a web server that runs php and does not create so many processes (today I checked the running processes list and there were like 90 of them called 'httpd', 300kb each), I only know these but I don't know if they will do the same or not:

- ngix
- lighttpd

Comment: fix your appache install, there's no need to replace it,

Comment: What is the actual problem here? Are you just looking to replace Apache 'because' or is there an actual problem like crashing or swapping or slowness? If 'like 90' processes is a problem, this can be remedied by analyzing and fixing the configuration.

Comment: What is wrong with having 90 processes?  If have a server with enough resources and a heavily loaded site, that might be a good number.

Comment: Regardless of whether you keep or replace Apache, you need to adjust your configuration to suit your system and your requirements. If you have limited resources on the server have a read of some of the numerous articles about configuring Apache to suit.

Answer (score 2):

What is your problem with the processes? They are just like threads. Would you mind a single process at 27,000kb?

Anyway, you should make sure to use FastCGI for PHP, as this won’t spawn a new php-process each request, but use one again and again. This may also reduce memory footage.

FastCGI is included in lighttpd and also works in Apache httpd.

Comment: Process are *not* just like threads: they are similar in some ways, but vastly different in others.

Comment: mod_php never spawns PHP processes. *runs*

Comment: Yea, you need one thread per connected user so if you have a busy site, expect there to be a lot of httpd processes spawning and dying.

Comment: @drew010 The number of threads (and/or process) required per connection is highly dependent upon web-server and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The best for performance is without a doubt [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/WhyUseIt). I have run nginx before on a 128MB VPS with Sql lite without any issues.